# Getting obfuscated uuids in url querystring

Tags: url, browser, query-string

I have an api, user from web pages, that is open to the web and have parameters such as `userid=b757bb72-0373-4222-a849-3b726db5e6cc`.
On the server side I noticed I occasionally get some userid=&D or `userid=jmrMzJ6wfX_LvoP9yiuCzYITeq6AwUf-_viGcRebsykK7YjM2XM8`.
This does not happen from a specific page or source, or any other parameters that have commonality.
all other parameters (not UUID type) are OK.

Is there a browser plugin or something else that can cause this corruption?